# If you drop a coin inside a car that is slowing down, where will the coin fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, free-fall

> If you drop a coin inside a car that is deccelerating, where will the coin fall with respect to the vertical where you dropped it?

My thoughts where since it still has a velocity forwards, even though it is deccelerating, it will launch forward to the vertical that you dropped it, isn't it?

Comment: It will fall into the crack between the seats that is the most awkward to retrieve it from…

Comment: You must have tried it - what happened?

Comment: @JonCuster  No, that spot is already occupied by the car keys you dropped as you were trying to start the car...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the coin is released, the only force acting on it is gravity so it will not be undergoing any horizontal acceleration. However, an observer in the car (a decelerating, non inertial, frame of reference) will see the coin launch forward with respect to the vertical, as you stated, attributing the forward acceleration to some pseudo force, which in actuality is simply the inertia of the coin.

On the other hand an observer along the side of the road, an inertial reference frame, will observe no horizontal deceleration of the coin after release. The observer will simply see the coin moving with the same velocity with respect to the road it had before being released. But the observer on the road will see the released coin moving forward with respect to other objects within the car, which of course are decelerating.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When your car decelerates, your head tries to move forward relative to the car.  You have to exert some effort to prevent that motion.  Why should a falling coin be any different than your head?